# Database with the historical prices of most popular products in U.S.?

Tags: data-request, usa, products, historical, prices

Is there an open database that would contained the historical prices of the most popular products in U.S.? At best with the product classification, so that it would be possible to make analysis, how prices of various product groups have changed in the history.

For example, how the price of tools have changed in U.S. in XIX century.

Answer (score 2):

The [CPI indices](http://www.bls.gov/cpi/#tables) from the Bureau of Labor and Statistics is probably what you're looking for. While it doesn't tell you what the price of 12 ounces of Coca Cola is, it does tell you what the average price of, say, "carbonated beverages" is over time. It will take some munging, but the [raw data is located here](ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ap/)

Comment: You may also be interested in this answer related to the CPI: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15/is-the-data-used-to-calculate-the-usa-cpi-public